# StackLayout not re-appearing after backgrounding

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently developing a Xamarin.Forms app that queries an API for updates every 15 seconds. I have used the `MessagingCenter` to perform this long runnimg task as it will continue to run even when the app is backgrounded. I have currently only added this code for the Android project as it makes use of a `Service` I was working from this and have adjusted it slightly to meet my requirements: https://github.com/RobGibbens/XamarinFormsBackgrounding

When the task receives it's payload, it renders the information as children of a  `StackLayout` that makes up the main content of the page. (The page is sat within a tabholder if that makes a difference)

Whilst the app is in the foreground everything works as expected, once it is backgrounded it still works with no issues, I can see from the console that the app is still making the correct API calls and receiving the correct data back, however once the app is brought back to the foreground, the `StackLayout` and all the content on the page appears to reload as if opening the app for the first time.

I then still try to update the `StackLayout` using it's `x:Name` and receive no errors, however nothing changes on the screen.

I have tried even changing the `BackgroundColor` with no change, but if I `Console.WriteLine(layout.BackgroundColor.ToString());` it will come up with the *new* colour, rather than the one on the screen.

What I fear may be happening is that it is creating a new layout when it comes back to the foreground, but holding the old layout in memory so any code is making changes to the old version, rather than the new one on screen.

If anyone can explain this behaviour in a way I can understand and suggest a fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you noticed this behaviour in the release mode? I had some troubles as you've described, but I was checking it in debug mode, and there's a lot of things that really doesn't working as expected when using background services or even broadcast receivers

Comment: Just tested and get the same issue on both debug and release.

Comment: One more try: uninstall the previous version the shared runtime and the other xamarin package that is installed automatically when the deploy is made in debug mode. It looks like an [instance state](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/activity_lifecycle/saving_state_walkthrough/#Adding_Code_to_Preserve_Instance_State) issue on XF that I couldn't figure out =/

Comment: Uninstalled anything mono or xamarin related but unfortunately the same issue. That article looks interesting though so I will put some time aside to see if the answer is in there

Comment: I'm sorry. Please, share the answer, if you get it. It'll be helpful. Good luck